# how to import project which has a library in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

i am getting diff gradle configuration when i migrate eclipse project has without  library and with library. i am getting error when importing project with libary.does any know  the exact build.graddle, settings.gradle?

1)without library project build.gradle

```
     buildscript {
       repositories {
    mavenCentral()
       }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
     }
 }
     apply plugin: 'android'

      dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

      android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

2)with library build.gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'android'

        dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
       compile project(':sdk:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-                play-services_lib')
  }

 android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

}

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  mimimum supported gradle version 0.6.8.1. some thing like that